# Não consigo ler uma entrada com espaços

Tags: c, string, input

Eu fiz a seguinte função para dar entrada nos dados:

```
void entrada_dados(Time* time, int i){
    fscanf(stdin, "%s %d %d", time[i].nome, &time[i].gols_marcados, &time[i].gols_sofridos);
};
```

Um exemplo de input seria:

```
2
santos
30
23
inter
35
30
```

Chamo ela na main da seguinte maneira:

```
int main(void) {

  int n = 0;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    entrada_dados(time, i);
 }
```

A ideia é chamar ela de acordo com a quantidade de times que vão ser inseridos nos parametros. Até então funciona tudo certo, o problema é quando eu tenho que inserir um time que tenha um espaço entre o nome, por exemplo: São Paulo.

Na saida, São Paulo fica como dois times diferentes e isso acaba bugando tudo. Tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
void entrada_dados(Time* time, int i){
    fscanf(stdin, "%[^\n] %d %d", time[i].nome, &time[i].gols_marcados, &time[i].gols_sofridos);
};
```

Mas também não funcionou.

Outra maneira que eu tentei foi:

```
void entrada_dados(Time* time, int i){
    fgets(time[i].nome, 100, stdin);
    scanf("%d", &time[i].gols_marcados);
    scanf("%d", &time[i].gols_sofridos);
  }
```

Mas também não funcionou. Tentei algumas outras coisas, mas também sem sucesso. Alguém pode explicar onde eu tô errando?

Answer (score 0):

> Alguém pode explicar onde eu tô errando?

Nunca mistures `fgets()` com `scanf()` (ou `fscanf()`).
Usa sempre, exclusivamente, `fgets()` pata obter input do utilizador.

```
void entrada_dados(Time *time, int i) {
    char temp[100];
    fgets(time[i].nome, 100, stdin); // obtem "Sao Paulo\n"
    time[i].nome[strcspn(time[i].nome, "\n")] = 0; // remove o newline final
    fgets(temp, sizeof temp, stdin); // obtem, por exemplo, "30\n"
    time[i].gols_marcados = strtol(temp, NULL, 10); // falta validacao de erros
    fgets(temp, sizeof temp, stdin); // obtem, por exemplo, "23\n"
    time[i].gols_sofridos = strtol(temp, NULL, 10); // falta validacao de erros
}
```